# Angular .net core and server sessions

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was wondering if it is still a thing to use server sessions to store info?

I have a website in angular, using a backend in c#, and at the moment, when the front needs data, it polls the backend that will get the data through its own api, and deliver it to the front. For each request on the frontend, the backend needs to redo the work. I would love to store the data in the backend.

Couple of years back, when I did c# dev, I used serversessions for that. Is this still a thing? When I search server session and angular, I do not find any good results.

Regards

Comment: Hi Hedi, this is quite a broad question, it would help to narrow it down so you would get better answers. Answer to your question could be: If you don't want to repeat the same work on the backend over and over again, use caching. Is it helpful? Probably not...

Comment: It is helpful! But I am talking about server sessions and asking if they are still being used?

Comment: Okay, I will try to answer your question then.

Answer (score 0):

Server sessions exists, if you implement them on the backend. Not sure what is the exact implementation for your C# backend, though.

Once you have a server session created you can send back a response to you Angular app with `Set-Cookie` header ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)), which will store you server session in the browser cookies.

`Set-Cookie` can contain limitation to send cookie back to backend only for certain domain or path, so you have to be mindful about that.

But when your app successfully stored cookie on the browser and it's attached to requests, then you can use this session on the backend to return cached response to avoid doing same work again for each request.

Comment: It this way of working used often? Or are other methods recommended?
If the c# backends needs to poll an external api every time the frontend needs info, and that info does not change often. What would the best way to store the info in the backend? Using a server session, or something else?

Comment: I believe server session should not contain all your cached information. It should be rather identifier/key, which you can use to retrieve saved data from memory cache or some in-memory database.